# Beego and Https

Tags: go, https, beego

Tried to set up https, as described here: https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/401 and got this in the logs:

```
2016/09/28 14:05:34 [I] [asm_amd64.s:2086] https server Running on https://127.0.0.1:10443
2016/09/28 14:05:37 [server.go:2315] [HTTP] http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:65365: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

I am running it on Windows 10. Any one got Beego working with https? I used self signed certificate, which works fine for generic golang https simple program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was testing in Chrome and a Chrome extension called Postman. Figured out the self signed certificate need to be accepted by Chrome by setting the chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost flag.

Another solution was to use Microsoft Edge.