# How to support HTTPS in Beego

Tags: go, https, beego

I want my beego website to support https.

There are another post [Beego and Https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790681/beego-and-https). I try that method enable chrome setting **chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost** or open url with Microsoft Edge. It's still show **This site can’t be reached**.

---

Environment

- go version go1.10 windows/amd64
- Beego     : 1.10.1

My step is:

1. Install googleapis.cer to my windows 10 computer.
2. Copy googleapis.cer and googleapis.keyfile to `D:\Go_workspace\src\myproject`
3. Edit `D:\Go_workspace\src\myproject\conf\app.conf`

   ```
   appname = myproject
   runmode = prod
   [dev]
   httpaddr = "127.0.0.1"
   HTTPPort = 9100
   [prod]
   httpaddr = "127.0.0.1"
   HTTPSPort = 9099
   httpsaddr = "127.0.0.1"
   EnableHTTPS = true
   EnableHttpTLS = true
   HTTPSCertFile = "googleapis.cer"
   HTTPSKeyFile = "googleapis.key"  
   [test]
   HTTPSPort = 9099
   ```
4. Run my project with the bee tool command **....\bin\bee run**

I get the following message and show message **This site can’t be reached** when I go to URL https://127.0.0.1:9099  :

```
2018/11/09 10:07:56.251 [I] [asm_amd64.s:2361]  http server Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080
2018/11/09 10:07:56.253 [I] [asm_amd64.s:2361]  https server Running on https://127.0.0.1:9099
2018/11/09 10:07:56.293 [C] [asm_amd64.s:2361]  ListenAndServeTLS:  listen tcp 127.0.0.1:9099: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a a possible race condition in `beego` that makes it intermittent to run both HTTP and HTTPS together. You can see this in `app.go`

```
if BConfig.Listen.EnableHTTPS || BConfig.Listen.EnableMutualHTTPS {
    go func() {
        //...
        app.Server.Addr = // the Addr is set to the value of HTTPS addr
        // ListenAndServeTLS()
    }()
}
if BConfig.Listen.EnableHTTP {
    go func() {
        app.Server.Addr = addr // the Addr is set to the valu of HTTP addr
        // ListenAndServe()
    }()
}
```

As you can see the `Server.Addr` is set on different goroutines which is a data race.

So I would suggest that you run your app exclusively on HTTPS unless you want to patch `beego` itself.

e.g. in your app.conf:

```
EnableHTTP = false
EnableHTTPS = true
```

Comment: Cool! It's work. Thank @ssemilla. But my website is still not secure, I need to use the global trusted https certificate.